# Why does len() execute __set__ of my class?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, descriptor, magic-function

I've implemented a [custom model field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24974600/1079110) in Django. It is an image field that allows assiging an URL string to load an image from, in addition to directly assigning a file.

```
import uuid
import urllib.request

from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageFileDescriptor


class UrlImageFileDescriptor(ImageFileDescriptor):
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # If a string is used for assignment, it is used as URL
        # to fetch an image from and store it on the server.
        if isinstance(value, str):
            try:
                response = urllib.request.urlopen(value)
                image = response.read()
                name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.png'
                value = ContentFile(image, name)
            except:
                print('Error fetching', value)
                pass
        super().__set__(instance, value)


class UrlImageField(models.ImageField):
    descriptor_class = UrlImageFileDescriptor
```

In general, the field works. But for some reason, Django itself internally assigns string values to it. Every time a query set of models using the field gets filtered, `__set__` is called with a string so that the print statement in the except clause fires `Error fetching upload/to/50e170bf-61b6-4670-90d1-0369a8f9bdb4.png`.

I could narrow down the call to [`django/db/models/query.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/78bff08341cfd5b729697c13a7478e83726782d1/django/db/models/query.py#L349) from Django 1.7c1.

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Performs the query and returns a single object matching the given
    keyword arguments.
    """
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.query.can_filter():
        clone = clone.order_by()
    clone = clone[:MAX_GET_RESULTS + 1]
    num = len(clone) # This line causes setting of my field
    if num == 1:
        return clone._result_cache[0]
    # ...
```

Why is the line causing my field's `__set__` to get executed? I could validate the input value to be a valid URL to work around this, but I'd like to know the reason first.

Comment: Can you show the complete traceback at the point where the error occurs (i.e., inside your `except` clause)?

Comment: @BrenBarn Here is a [link to the full traceback](http://pastebin.com/D27CA2QP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The story is there in your traceback.  To get the length of the query:

```
File "C:\repository\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  350.         num = len(clone)
```

It fetches all the query results into a list:

```
File "C:\repository\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  122.         self._fetch_all()
File "C:\repository\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _fetch_all
  966.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
```

For each query result, it creates a model object using the data from the db:

```
File "C:\repository\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in iterator
  275.                     obj = model(*row_data)
```

To create the model object, it sets each field of the model:

```
File "C:\repository\virtualenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in __init__
  383.                 setattr(self, field.attname, val)
```

Which winds up calling `__set__` on your custom model field:

```
File "C:\repository\invoicepad\apps\customer\fields.py" in __set__
  18.                           response = urllib.request.urlopen(value)
```

It's hard to say more about the larger-scale reasons behind this, both because I don't know that much about Django and because I don't know what your db structure is like.  However, essentially it looks whatever database field populates your `UriImageField` has data in it that is not actually valid for the way you implemented the descriptor.  (For instance, judging from your error, the db has `'upload/to/50e170bf-61b6-4670-90d1-0369a8f9bdb4.png'` but there is not actually such a file.)

Comment: Thanks! The path is what Django stores in the database for a file field. I didn't know that Django assigns the plain string to the file field first. The file exists at that path, but it's relative to the media root on the same server, so fetching by URL fails.